# Why is the accept ratio not displayed anymore?

Tags: support, questions, accepted-answer, users, site-statistics

Why does the percentage of questions for which a user has accepted an answer not appear anymore? Is there a way to see this information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was [a decision made by the good folks at Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164654). See the question, answers, and comments [there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164654) for the whys and wherefores.

There is a way to see this information: go through [every question a person asked](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/170/msh210?tab=questions) and see how many ([that qualify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16729)) he accepted. Or write a query for it on [the Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Awesome! How did I never know about the data explorer?

Answer (score 3):

The [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/) still returns a value for accept_rate for a user query.

For example: http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/users/883?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=judaism&filter=!nTBZKAKmnK returns a key:value pair of `{"accept_rate":63}`.

Comment: Could this be a bug?

Comment: <strike>Hm? Which part?</strike> I don't think so. I'm pretty sure I've seen something on meta that says it's intentional. Still looking.